# Scrapy spider doesn't call 'callback' function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to perform the crawl with the spider below, but it doesn't call 'callback' function. My spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ScreenerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'screener'
    allowed_domains = ['finviz.com']
    start_urls = ['https://finviz.com/screener.ashx']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&r=[0-9]{2}']),
             callback='parse_screener', follow=True)
    ]


    def parse_screener(self, response):
        self.logger.warning('lalala')
```

When I run this spider it doesn't print 'lalala' in the terminal, i.e. doesn't call 'parse_screener' function. I wrote this spider as exactly shown in the documentation. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your allow clause. It's regex so you must escape special symbols like '?'. This works fine (backslash before ?):

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['https://finviz.com/screener.ashx\?v=111&r=[0-9]{2}']), callback='parse_screener', follow=True)
```